# Trouble querying Mysql database from web

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble setting up a query, it seems very simple but I cannot seem to determine if my database logic is incorrect or whether the query is incorrect.

There is one database with 3 tables, clients, orders and package.

The clients table has 3 fields, ID{primary key auto increment), email (varchar) and organisation (varchar).

The orders table has 10 fields, ID(from above), OderID (PRimary, autoincrement), WorkID (from package table), and othr fields relating to file paths, comments, feedback and date.

The package table has 2 fields, WorkID (primary Key autoincrem), name(varchar)

This is what I want the query to do:

> The query must get all the rows from orders table where WorkID= 1 and must get the organisation field from clients based on each order. I am then going to order the rows by date.

Am I meant to be suing a join to get this query to work or is there a flaw in the database logic? Now yes I already know there is an error below as i am not comparing an ID from the two tables, but what I want to happen is for it to first get all the rows from orders where WorkID = 1 then add the clients.organisation field to each row found from WorkId = 1 where  ID from clients corresponds to the ID assigned to that row.

Thanks for any help

```
$query =    "SELECT * 
             FROM orders INNER JOIN clients ON orders.ID = clients.ID
             WHERE WorkID = 1
             ORDER BY Date DESC";
```

**WORKING NOW**___*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____------------------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Ok guys ive got the query working but for some odd reason the number of rows being echoed in while loop i have set up is always 1 less than num_rows. Anyone have any idea as to why? This is my echo

```
<?php
include "../includes/connect.php";

$query =    "SELECT * 
             FROM orders INNER JOIN clients ON orders.ID = clients.ID
             WHERE WorkID = 1
             ORDER BY Date DESC";

$result = mysqli_query( $link , $query );


?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="qH5HloAtcJbjEVuEx3vDy_Rmj7Zjw8Mtsuuqdrd1c3Y" />
<link href="../styles/dark-main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../styles/nivo-slider.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href="../styles/jquery.galleryview-3.0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/page-scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.galleryview-3.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.timers-1.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/validator.js"></script>


</head>

<body class="portfolio">

<!--TOPBAR STARTS HERE-->
<?php include"../includes/topbar.php"; ?>
<!--TOPBAR ENDS HERE-->

<!--HEADER STARTS HERE-->
<?php include"../includes/header.php"; ?>
<!--HEADER ENDS HERE-->

<!--SLIDER STARTS HERE-->
<?php include"../includes/slider.php"; ?>
<!--SLIDER ENDS HERE-->

<!--MIANCONTENT STARTS HERE-->

<div class="contentcontainer">

    <div class="contentcontainercenter">



    <div class="portfoliowrapper">
    <h2>Portfolio</h2>
    <div class="box">

    <div id="conversionworks" class="conversionwork">
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <span class="message"> message </span>

    <div class="blockwrapper">

    <?php
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ){                           
  echo '
  <div class="itembox">
    <div class="imagewrapper">
    <a class="thumbnail" href=""><img src='. $row['ThumbPath'].' /><span><img src='. $row['FilePath'].' /></span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="detailsbox">
    Company:<span class="details"> '.$row['Organisation'].' </span><br />
    Theme:<span class="details">  '.$row['Theme'].' </span><br />
    Uses:<span class="details">  '.$row['Tech Used'].' </span>
    </div>
    </div>'      
;}
?>
```

Also i have a question i regards to safety of a database. I have file paths stored in the database which get echoed according to each record fetch no user interaction all done via the server on page load, is it insecure to do so?

2nd question i have mutiple queries on the 1 page, what would be the best way to include each query where it is required? (Would putting it in a separate file and calling it before the echo be best?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need something like that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN clients c ON (c.id = o.id)
WHERE o.WorkID = 1
ORDER BY `Date` DESC
```

Some side notices : you should change your column naming convention to something more descriptive (I'm talking about `orders.id` which is in your case is a reference to  `clients.id`). Personally, I prefer to use `id` as a primary key in each table. Some people like to name it as `[TABLE_NAME]_id`, in your case `order_id`, `client_id`. Secondly, don't use *; list all required fields. Also, I'd recommend to use a newer sql syntax for joining table (use `JOIN` keyword instead of listing all tables in `FROM` clause).

Comment: hi yes i will change the naming convention because even im getting confused with it atm lol. Um so i got it working, but i am having trouble echoing the results. When i echo out the number of rows it is correct. But when it actually comes to echoing out the div with the information in a while loop it is always echoinh 1 less than the num rows? Would you know why it is doing this?

Comment: Your loop looks ok to me (assuming you called '$result = mysqli_query([query_string])` before it). If you provide more information about which record is missing (I'd expect the first one or the last one) and the full code, I'll try to give a better advise.

Comment: yea it is the first record that is missing. Ill update my question with the full code. Thanks once again

Comment: The problem is that you call `$row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result );` not only in the loop, but before it (actually, in the loop you start with the second row). Each `fetch` command that gets the record from `$result` moves the pointer to the record to the next one.

Comment: Remove the first `$row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result );` (after `$result = ...`) and you will get all the results

Answer (score 0):

Yes using a join would be what you want to do (a left join actually).  You can read about them [here](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php), or put your tables into a readable state; and I can give you an example.